# Entity Framework: using inherited type to show missing properties of the base type

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, inheritance

Using Entity Framework 6 database first approach (oracle db) I want to map two different entities to the same table, which is used for storing files. The table has the following columns:

- ID (int)
- MIMETYPE (varchar)
- BLOB (blob)

The first entity (UPL_DOCUMENTS) **should not** contain the BLOB attribute. Entity RAW_UPL_DOCUMENTS, instead, should also have the blob. Each entity of one type should relate to exactly one entity of the other type.

I'm doing this because I want to expose this data via a restful web API and I want to return the BLOB only when the specific endpoint for files is called. In other cases, because the files entities will be listed as Navigation Properties of other entities, I want to keep the HTTP response lighter.

For this reason, using database first approach, I created entity UPL_DOCUMENTS and removed the BLOB property using the Designer. Then I manually added a new entity which has *Base Type* set to UPL_DOCUMENTS, called it RAW_UPL_DOCUMENTS, and added to it only the blob property.

The Designer clearly shows the inheritance relation between the two types.

If I try to validate my model, I get the following error:

```
EntityTypes Model.UPL_DOCUMENTS, Model.RAW_UPL_DOCUMENTS are being mapped
to the same rows in table UPL_DOCUMENTS. Mapping conditions can be used 
to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.
```

Mapping objects "to the same rows in table UPL_DOCUMENTS" is exactly what I want to achieve, so I cannot understand how to prevent this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't give too much insight because I have no knowledge of Oracle, but sounds to me like you might want to use a Discriminator column. Have you read up on the Table-Per-Hierarchy and Table-Per-Type structures? [Check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716683(v=vs.100).aspx) for more info.

Comment: I read it but it seems that they cover different scenarios: the Table-Per-Hierarchy, for example, implies that I can map records having one null column to type A, and records having another null column to type B, both inheriting from type C. But in my case I want **all** records being both of type A and B, where A inherit from B.

Comment: Table-Per-Type instead seems covering the scenario where there are multiple types in the same table, and they are distinguished by foreign keys in other tables

Comment: I think that having an abstract class C that both A and B inherit from, and only having B implement your BLOB column, might be the cleanest approach (which is table-per-hierarchy). Another option might be putting that BLOB on your class `A`, but making the getters & setters private, which would effectively hide it. I'm not sure of what other options you would have in this situation.

Comment: If I cannot solve this issue using the Designer I'll create a database view for that entity not containing the blob